# Is there any difference between the "new Contract()" syntax and the assembly "create" opcode?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-deployment, yul, create

Is there any difference between the two following ways of creating a smart contract via a smart contract?

```
function create_v1() external {
    Contract c = new Contract();
}
```

```
function create_v2() external {
    bytes memory deploymentBytecode = type(Contract).creationCode;
    address contractAddress;
    assembly {
        contractAddress := create(0, add(deploymentBytecode, 0x20), mload(deploymentBytecode))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only meaningful difference is that the first version checks that the deployment was successful. The address returned from `create` can indeed be `address(0)`, and in this case it means that the deployment failed (for example `Contract` may revert during the constructor).

So, to make the second version equivalent to the first we can add a simple check:

```
function create_v2() external {
    bytes memory deploymentBytecode = type(Contract).creationCode;
    address contractAddress;
    assembly {
        contractAddress := create(0, add(deploymentBytecode, 0x20), mload(deploymentBytecode))
        if iszero(contractAddress) {
            // we can forward the error message
            returndatacopy(0, 0, returndatasize())
            revert(0, returndatasize())
        }
    }
}
```

Tip: a rough way to check what solidity is doing under the hood, is compiling a contract using

```sh
solc Foo.sol --ir
```

For `create_v1` we can see the following (adapted, comments are mine)

```
function fun_create_v1_16() {
    let _1 := allocate_unbounded()
    let _2 := add(_1, datasize("Contract_4"))  // Contract_4 is the contract we want to deploy
    if or(gt(_2, 0xffffffffffffffff), lt(_2, _1)) { panic_error_0x41() }  // memory overflow check
    datacopy(_1, dataoffset("Contract_4"), datasize("Contract_4"))
    _2 := abi_encode_tuple__to__fromStack(_2)  // does nothing :|

    let expr_13_address := create(0, _1, sub(_2, _1))

    if iszero(expr_13_address) { revert_forward_1() }  // check create worked - forward returndata in case

    let var_c_9_address := expr_13_address
}
```